# Applescript "mixed credentials" error

Tags: applescript

I asked this question over on the Apple Communities and got a grand total of ZERO responses. You guys seem a whole lot smarter, so thought I would ask here to see what you think.

An error has started occuring when I attempt to trigger an Applescript via an external process. The console error is as follows:

12/09/2012 11:01:39.205 osascript[269]: Scripting addition loading restricted to system domains because this process has mixed credentials (issetugid=0 r/e uid=501/0 gid=20/20)

When I run the script locally on the Mac(Mini - Mountain Lion 10.8.1) it works perfectly.

What is happening is as follows.

I have a MacMini as a music server in a home automation environment powered by a Crestron processor. The MacMini is connected to two zones, one via the Optical output and another to a DAC from one of the USB ports. When I selected "Listen to iTunes" in one of the two zones the controller sends a command via UDP to a program running on the MacMini which triggers the scripts to change to the appropriate audio out.

All was working well until yesterday when all of a sudden the program triggering the script, whilst reporting that it has executed the correct script correctly, isn't switching the output and the above message is appearing on the console.

I have read what I can on here and as such have reset the PRAM and SMC (all three dongs...) and deleted the script triggering program, run Clean My Mac and rebooted, all to no avail.

Can anyone help me with this, it has to be something simple given that it was working...surely? I haven't run an update or changed anything else that I can think of.....

Any and all thoughts and input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that you have an add-on to applescript called a "Scripting addition" installed, and that's causing the error. Most likely you do not need this add-on to perform your applescript code. So I would remove all scripting additions from my system and see if the applescript still works.

Search your system for scripting additions... ~/Library/ScriptingAdditions and /Library/ScriptingAdditions.

If you do need to do something that the scripting addition is doing for you, then there's probably other ways to perform the same task without the add-on.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response. As far as I can tell the "script triggerer" (an App called iControl) hasn't installed any Scripting Additions. In fact there are only two present in either directory, "Digital Hub Scripting.osax" and "Standard Additions.osax". I will contact the iControl developer to be certain, but I already sent him the error message and he is scratching his head too!

Comment: Well be certain not to remove either of those osax files. It seems you're looking in your /System/Library/ScriptingAdditions folder. That folder is only for apple-supplied system stuff so don't touch anything in there. If you didn't find any other scripting additions in the folders I mentioned, then I would guess it's an issue with iControl. Good luck.

Comment: One other thought... if it's not a scripting additions problem, and it's not an iControl problem, then there is mention of a permissions issue. Have you repaired permissions on your computer? Maybe try that too.

Comment: I have repaired permissions a few times! I am talking to the developer who is on the case. He needs to be persuaded that it's his problem, but I am confident of getting there. Very many thanks for your help. Marc

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, there are other ways to do things. With applescript and core technologies of the operating system, you have all the tools to perform your automation without 3rd party applications. If you're interested in that then just post a new question on the topic.